# uisearchbar backgroundColor

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I tried to color the background of the searchbar so, but it does not work when i push search..

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
searchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

}
```

Answer (score 10):

Do you want to change the background of the search-bar OR tint-color of the search-bar? 
like this->
[image]

If yes then use this line of code

```
    searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Comment: could you please tell me what do u mean by background of search-bar! I mean can u post some image of your requirement by editing your answer.

Comment: Its bcoz i wrote the same line from your que in my code but it did nothing & in fact I also got the que what background of search bar it will change?

Comment: there is a property: backgroundColor in searchbar. how do I set it?

Comment: I would like to set the background color that is white(default)

Comment: If u go to `UISearchBar` Class Reference u will not find the `backgroundColor` property. It is the property of `UIView` which is superclass of `UISearchBar`. I think in Xcode u r getting it as intelligence when u type `searchbar.b` right?

Comment: Hey Thanks all for upvoting the answer. I am glad it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

```
change tintColor of searchBar

searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```